# Can't install google map pod in react-native-map

Tags: react-native, google-maps, cocoapods, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

I have an issue in installing google map pod in react-native-maps.
react-native-maps is working well without google map. But I have an issue when I add google map to iOS project.
Follow is my pod file

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'sa' do

    # React Native Maps dependencies
    rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
   pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
   pod 'GoogleMaps'
   pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'

   pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'

  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'saTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

target 'sa-tvOS' do
  # Pods for sa-tvOS

  target 'sa-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

when I start pod install, then shows following error:

```
JSON::ParserError - 416: unexpected token at '"Example/GoogleMapsDemos/Resources/ne'
```

Follow is my environment:

```
   CocoaPods : 1.9.3
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.15.6 (19G73)
       Xcode : 12.0.1 (12A7300)
         Git : git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

I hope your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is pod. After pod upgrade the issue is fixed